# Run in terminal not working

Tags: command-line, bash, execute-command

I am new to Ubuntu and I was trying to run this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo hello world
```

It works fine if I open the terminal first and manually invoke it. Like `./test`.
I have set "Ask each time" in file prefs:
[image]

This also works fine: 
[image]

Now I click Run in terminal. And Lo! **Nothing** happens.
I expect it to open the terminal and echo hello world. What am I doing wrong? 
This is a fresh installation of ubuntu along with windows from the ubuntu website.

Comment: Maybe it runs a new terminal, then ends and closes the terminal before you can notice it. Try adding `sleep 10` as the next line to keep it running for 10 more seconds to test it.

Comment: You can verify it with "echo hello world > ~/test.log" and look for the test.log.

Comment: By default the terminal closes automatically after your program finishes - in this case it's probably happening so fast that you can see it. You can change this in the "Profile preferences" in the terminal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Your problem:

The problem is that `echo hello world` executes within milliseconds, faster than the terminal window is able to pop up.

This means your script already exits before the terminal is visible and therefore its startup is cancelled and you see nothing.

#### Solution 1 - modify script and add a delay:

You can add a delay (here: 5 seconds) at the end of your script so that it runs longer and you have time to view the result before the script quits and the terminal window closes itself:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo hello world
sleep 5
```

#### Solution 2 - modify script and wait for a keypress:

You can also add a `read` command to the end of your script to wait for keyboard input before the script exits.

The `-s` parameter causes silent input i.e. your pressed key will not be echoed to the terminal.
`-n1` lets it read only one single character and returns immediately afterwards instead of waiting for <kbd>Enter</kbd> to be pressed.
The `-p "Press any key to exit..."` argument actually specifies the text to print before waiting for input.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo hello world
read -s -n1 -p "Press any key to exit..."
```

#### Solution 3 - change `gnome-terminal`'s preference to keep the window open:

Launch a `gnome-terminal` window, open the **Edit** menu and select **Profile preferences**. Navigate to the **Commands** tab. You will see a drop-down menu labelled **When command exits:**

[image]

Pick **Hold terminal open** here and close the settings window.

From now on when you double-click on a script and select to run it in a terminal, the window will no longer close itself but stay open and display a banner informing you about the script's exit status:

[image]

> *Warning!*
>   This setting also applies if you manually open a terminal window and try to close it by exiting Bash using the `exit` command or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> - I find it pretty annoying that the terminal window does not close any more then as well.

Comment: This, or you can add a line to expect the user to press [Enter] to exit.  For example: `echo -n  "Press enter to exit... "` and  `read key` afterwards.

Comment: Thank you. In windows, I was always able to see the console for like 0.5s even if it end very fast.